# Corona Physics not pushing bodies

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I am build a top down view game.
I have two physics bodies. The player and a house. I don't want the player to be able to walk where the house is. I have added the two bodies.

```
physics.addBody(part.house, "static", {shape=bodies.houses[1]})

physics.addBody(Player, {density=200,radius=30})
```

The shape of the house body is done in an array.

```
bodies.houses = {
                    {-120, 90, -60, 90, -60, 15, 30, 15, 110, -60, 110, -170, 30, -245, -120, -245},
                    {10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10},
                    {10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10}
                }
```

The body shape itself sits on the image perfectly. But the player can still run over the house. Please help.

--EDIT 1
The player is moved using this library

```
local StickLib   = require("lib_analog_stick")
```

Comment: have you try putting a physics body on the player? like dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shape of your building is not [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons) as required by the [corona docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html):

> [corona docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html): Polygonal shapes must be entirely convex. You cannot create shapes
>   with concave bends, for example a bowl or cup. To accomplish such a
>   task, you must assemble the body from multiple polygons, as explained
>   in Multi-Element Bodies below.
>
> [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons): In
>   a convex polygon, a line segment between two points on the boundary
>   never goes outside the polygon.

You can see it's not convex because the black line segment leaves the shape but both ends are on the boundaries. You can break off the bottom rectangle bit (under green line) into another body to fix this.

```
physics.addBody(part.house, "static",
   {shape={-120, 15, -60, 15, 30, 15, 110, -60, 110, -170, 30, -245, -120, -245}},
   {shape={-120, 90, -60, 90, -60, 15, -120, 15}}
)
```

[image: Non convex shape]

Comment: And this will prevent collisions?

Comment: @TomHanson It is necessary to detect collisions properly. If the polygons are concave the behavior is undefined so collisions may be missed, incorrect or it may produce other strange behaviors.